# How to edit a form field to add some condition using Django template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form (`ModelForm`, `Model` and `view`).

Everything works fine but there is a new requirement in the project and one of the text-input is no longer simple, I need to use some Django template (`if condition`).

This is exactly the HTML representation of the input that I need (and it works separately):

```
<input class="form-control project" id="project" name="project" type="text" {% if entry.project %}value="{{ entry.project.id }}: {{ entry.project.name }}"{% endif %}>
```

What I have tried:

- edit the attributes of the widget in the `forms.py` so that it looks as close as possible to the HTML code above but it has been impossible for me.

**UPDATED with the solution provided by @bdbd [SOLVED]**

`forms.py`:

```
class ExpenseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = ['project']
        widgets = {
            'project': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control ts_project',
                    'id': 'ts_project',
                    'name': 'ts_project',
                    }
                ),
        }
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            entry = kwargs.pop('entry')
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            if entry:
                self.fields['project'].widget.attrs.update({'value': entry.project})
```

The code doesn't work but I can't think of another way to make it work. `class, id and name` working as expected if I delete `value` and all the Django template code.

How can I add a condition through django templates to a widget / field of a Django form?

Comment: Try to put the dynamic part in `__init__`. You can modify the attrs of the widget like this: `self.fields['project'].widget.attrs.update({'value': entry.project})`

Comment: Could you provide an example as an answer? (so that I can accept your answer)

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ExpenseForm`, you can modify the attributes of the widget based on some arbitrary criteria using `__init__`.

For example, say you pass an `entry` object in your form, and you want to modify a widget based on that:

```py
class ExpenseForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        entry = kwargs.pop('entry')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if entry:
            self.fields['project'].widget.attrs.update({'value': entry.project})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to be working now (cache issue). Thanks a lot!